# Block Google requests to 16k using pf firewall

Tags: security, firewall, freebsd, filtering, pf

I'd like to block access to Google search using [PF](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) after the threshold of 17500 requests (connection established) in 24h, from a host running FreeBSD 9.

What I came up with, after reading [pf-faq](ftp://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/doc/pf-faq.txt) is this rule:

```
pass out on $net proto tcp from any to 'www.google.com' port www flags S/SA keep state (max-src-conn 200, max-src-conn-rate 17500/86400)
```

NOTE: *86400 are 24h in seconds.*

The rule should work, but PF is smart enough to know that www.google.com resolves in 5 different IPs. So my `pfctl -sr` output gives me this:

```
pass out on vte0 inet proto tcp from any to 173.194.44.81 port = http flags S/SA keep state (source-track rule, max-src-conn 200, max-src-conn-rate 17500/86400, src.track 86400)
pass out on vte0 inet proto tcp from any to 173.194.44.82 port = http flags S/SA keep state (source-track rule, max-src-conn 200, max-src-conn-rate 17500/86400, src.track 86400)
pass out on vte0 inet proto tcp from any to 173.194.44.83 port = http flags S/SA keep state (source-track rule, max-src-conn 200, max-src-conn-rate 17500/86400, src.track 86400)
pass out on vte0 inet proto tcp from any to 173.194.44.80 port = http flags S/SA keep state (source-track rule, max-src-conn 200, max-src-conn-rate 17500/86400, src.track 86400)
pass out on vte0 inet proto tcp from any to 173.194.44.84 port = http flags S/SA keep state (source-track rule, max-src-conn 200, max-src-conn-rate 17500/86400, src.track 86400)
```

PF creates 5 different rules, 1 for each IP that Google resolves. However I have the sense - *without being 100% sure, I didn't had the chance to test it* - that the number 17500/86400 applies for each IP. If that's the case - **please confirm** - then it's not what I want.

In pf-faq there's another option called `source-track-global`:

> source-track
>
> ```
> This option enables the tracking of number of states created per source IP
> address. This option has two formats:
>
>   + source-track rule - The maximum number of states created by this rule
>     is limited by the rule's max-src-nodes and max-src-states options.
>     Only state entries created by this particular rule count toward the
>     rule's limits.
>
>   + source-track global - The number of states created by all rules that
>     use this option is limited. Each rule can specify different
>     max-src-nodes and max-src-states options, however state entries
>     created by any participating rule count towards each individual rule's
>     limits.
>
> The total number of source IP addresses tracked globally can be controlled
> via the src-nodes runtime option.
> ```

I tried to apply **source-track-global** in the above rule without success. How can I use this option in order to achieve my goal?

*Any thoughts or comments are more than welcome since I'm an amateur and don't fully understand PF yet.*

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on *without success*? Do you get error message? Or does it has no effect? Post your pf.conf if possible (mask all real external ip).

Comment: "source-track-global" is not made for that sort of thing. It doesn't work by accumulating data from each different ip. I changed my pf.conf since then, but I can look at my backups if you wanna know the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `source-track` option does apply per-rule, so you are not restricting "Google to X req/day", you are restricting each individual address to that limit.

I give you two solutions here. One is simple and approximate, the other is harder and sharper.

**Solution 1**

Transform the condition so as to match all servers of interest in one rule. The simplest approach is to use a CIDR specification, e.g.:

`pass out on vte0 inet proto tcp from any to 173.194.44.80/29 port http keep state (source-track rule, max-src-conn 200, max-src-conn-rate 17500/86400, src.track 86400)`

This matches hosts 173.194.44.80 through 173.194.44.86: two more than you want. You get 99% of the goal with 10% of the complexity. For most cases I would go this way. This specific case is particular because Google is one of the 2-3 organizations in the world to own a manifold netblocks and to often reappoint their addresses. For handling google, yahoo etc I wouldn't go for this solution.

**Solution 2**

Use `tag`, a very own beauty of PF. Tags allow you to stick a note on a packet and apply rules later on based on it. Here's an example for your case:

`pass out on vte0 proto tcp from any to 'www.google.com' port http tag TOGOOGLE
pass out quick on vte0 proto tcp tagged TOGOOGLE keep state (source-track rule, max-src-conn 200, max-src-conn-rate 17500/86400, src.track 86400)`

**Side notes**

- you need no longer `flags S/SA`: it's default for stateful connections
- specifying firewall rules that match by hostname is dangerous